# Rails includes nested relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, relationship

I need to query all posts from a specific user and include all comments and the user who belongs to the comment.

```
class User < ...
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
end

class Post < ...
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ...
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end

@posts = current_user.posts.include(:comments)
```

Is is possible to also get the comment user? I list a lot of posts and comments. I do not want to query each comment user.

Thx / Tobias

Answer (score 27):

Try

```
@posts = current_user.posts.includes( :comments => :user)
```

Read more about it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-multiple-associations)

Comment: Is it possible to limit the comment in this query. I only want the 5 latest comments to be included. If I loop shout.comments.limit(5) a new query is run

Comment: In my answer: `Post has_many :comments, :include => [:user], :limit => 5`

Comment: Yeah but I also wan't to fetch all comments on one page, or even paginate them?

Comment: Anyone know how this has changed in Rails 4 and 5 ? 

I cannot find any information on how this has changed and I'm stuck on this, upgrading my app from 3.2 to 5.0

Comment: Includes works the same in rails 4 and I think in 5 also

Answer (score 11):

How about include at the relation definition statement?

> :include
>       Specify second-order associations that should be eager loaded when this object is loaded.

```
class Post <
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, :include => [:user], :limit => 5
end
```

Comment: It looks like :include isn't a valid option (at least not with Rails 4.1), is there an alternative?