# Need a hand with a rails join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my app, I have four models - Users > Clients > Jobs > Tasks

I have all of the associations set up fine (as per here --> [Advice on RoR database schema and associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10764298/advice-on-ror-database-schema-and-associations)), but I'm stuck with a query.

Basically, what I'm doing is:

```
@potentialjobs = current_user.jobs.where(:status => "potential")
```

But in the results, I also want to include the client attrs in addition to the job attrs.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

*UPDATE*

Appreciate the suggestions below.

I thought this should have been pretty straightforward, but I'm beginning to think the problem must lie somewhere else in my codebase.

Whenever I try to `include` or `join` the client model in this query or as a second-order association in the model itself, I get the following error:

`uninitialized constant Job::Clients`

...and I'm not sure why. So, can anyone shed some light on this for me?

*ANOTHER UPDATE*

Solved - I had a pluralisation error in one of my models. Gah. Thanks all.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554498/rails-includes-nested-relations

Comment: Please post your model code.

Comment: Hi @SeanHill - no need. I realised the problem almost as soon as I typed. Pluralisation error in the model. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can access the client's fields through the association in both ways.

```
<% @potential_jobs.each do |job| %>
  <%= job.client.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I thought I could do that too, but I'm getting `undefined method client`